# Best practice for deploying administration area in Java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

On our public facing web server we have an administration area for our website and is accessed by going to:

http://www.ourapplication.com/admin

The admin area has basic CRUD functionality and we have this built into our Java EE application, but we want to separate this admin area to a different server behind our firewall so that it is accessible from our internal network only.

What's the best strategy for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* create one web application that really is a container for 2 separate applications. For example when I use ant and struts, when deploying a public facing site, I don't even compile `example.actions.admin` or `example.admin.*` in my public facing site, though I choose what models I want to compile and share with this app. I also set up my properties file to connect to a different database etc.

Then my admin app, deployed on an internal network, excludes the public actions as well. My setup is Struts specific, but I presume you can deploy different parts of your application to different servers while still using *parts* of the same shared codebase.

Actually I even have one app, that has a third app as part of it, a Java Webstart app that we launch from the admin app. It also shares the same models as the admin app.

From a code organization perspective, this is one Java application.  However from an application perspective, these are actually 3 separate applications.

Now just because you *can* do something... it doesn't really mean you *should*.

In my scenario, the very limited subset of classes we have in the public facing site is really all we need to build it. However without that caution, this *trick* could turn around and hurt you.

Comment: Yeah, see we'd like to create only one actual application, just so we can manage our code better and not have to make changes in two places if we modify the database and whatnot...

Comment: Just be sure to not even include any part of your admin in the public facing app. I use `src.excludes=**/*admin* **/*report*` and then I have additional properties which sets up which struts config I use in which app, and database access and whatnot. Actually this app started as 3 different apps, but we had to consolidate the code because it wasn't getting updated everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Create two separate webapps.

No reason to expose a potential security hole by having the admin code in the public site, and no reason to include all the public functionality in the internal/admin app.

Answer (score 1):

You can not serve parts of same application from different server selectively and that's a good thing.

Create a separate application for admin area and serve it from where ever you want.
If you do need or want your public facing webapp to have be able have access to this for what ever reason you can just create a link .

Answer (score 1):

> On our public facing web server we have an administration area for our
>   website and is accessed by going to
>   http://www.ourapplication.com/admin

To expose an administration facility over the public network is a real security hole.
Do you really need it running in production after everything has been configured and deployed correctly?If no then remove it. E.g. in Tomcat it is recomended to remove `manager` app.

If you really need it then filter the accessing IPs.
You don't mention which server you use but in Tomcat you could use a `Valve` or generally you could use a `Filter`
This way only local IP and the ones belonging in your private network can access it

Comment: Basically it's a custom content management system that business folk use to edit the site. Glassfish for app server and apps are proxied through Apache.